# desktopcouch-ubuntuone installation failure

Tags: installation, ubuntu-one, desktopcouch

I installed into ubuntu 11.10 and got message 
"desktopcouch-ubuntuone could not be installed"
???
Seems to work OK i.e., I can place a file in the folder and it's uploaded into the "cloud" and I can access it in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

desktopcouch-ubuntuone is no longer needed and is going to be removed in the next version. It is not used for file synchronization, but for database synchronization. It is being replaced by something else in future versions of Ubuntu One.

In other words, you don't have to worry about that error message.